# Where is libGL in NVIDIA proprietary drivers 460?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, opengl

I have to follow [this instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567383/dropbox-system-tray-icon-black-background) in order to restore the icon tray of my DropBox.

But I need to find the libGL.so that the NVIDIA proprietary drivers have installed.
But I cannot not.

The package `libnvidia-gl-460` does not contain any `libGL.so`:

```
$ dpkg -L libnvidia-gl-460
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/nvidia-ngx-updater
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_nvidia.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-cbl.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-eglcore.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glsi.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glvkspirv.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ngx.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-rtcore.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-tls.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvoptix.so.460.32.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so.460.32.03
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libnvidia-gl-460
/usr/share/doc/libnvidia-gl-460/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libnvidia-gl-460/copyright
/usr/share/glvnd
/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d
/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/10_nvidia.json
/usr/share/vulkan
/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d
/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json
/usr/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d
/usr/share/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/nvidia_layers.json
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_nvidia.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvoptix.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so
```

and I have a `/usr/lib/nvida` that does not contain such file.

Answer (score 1):

The `libGL.so` file is provided by `libgl-dev` package.

Install it by

```
 sudo apt install libgl-dev
```

But you may need `libGL.so.1` that is provided by `libgl1` package.

Most likely you need only

```
sudo apt install libgl1
```

And it is not related to Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: The thread I linked says that the NVIDIA proprietary driver provides their own version of libGL. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/624103/176654)

Comment: This is an old post.

Comment: @raffaem nvidia-340 was the last nvidia package to supply it.  try apt-file search libGL to see sources.