# DropBox system tray icon is black - and no libGL in NVIDIA proprietary drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, icons, dropbox, system-tray

The system tray icon of DropBox is completely black and thus indistinguishable from the background.

In order to solve the problem, [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567383/dropbox-system-tray-icon-black-background) suggests to substitute DropBox's `libGL` with NVIDIA's `libGL` to solve the problem.

But my NVIDIA proprietary drivers do not have any `libGL`, and when I asked [I was told](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308979/where-is-libgl-in-nvidia-proprietary-drivers-460/1308980?noredirect=1#comment2227004_1308980) that the NVIDIA proprietary drivers are not supposed to have `libGL`.

How can I turn the color of the DropBox tray icon from black to white?

System information:

```
Dropbox daemon version: 113.4.507
Dropbox command-line interface version: 2020.03.04
I have Kubuntu 20.10. 
Linux kernel v. 5.8.0-38-generic. 
NVIDIA proprietary driver v: 460.32.03
```